# Creating Texture Atlases with Folder References rather than Groups

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, sktextureatlas

Many of the resources in my project are located in folder references rather than groups, i.e. blue, not yellow folders. This is for a number of reasons - I considered both solutions, and folder references were the better option (I do things like

`imagePaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:directory];`

)

According to [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-texture_atlas/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013290-CH1-SW1) I just rename the containting folder, however if I rename any of the folders containing the assets to *folder*.atlas, this is taken literally as part of the path name, and none of the contents are found.

Is the only way to do this to generate the atlases manually using something like TexturePacker? My code is rather heavily dependent on pathnames, so I would have to do a lot of re-writing...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve here.
Texture atlasing takes all images in your name.atlas folder in project, puts them into one image, adds a plist so that it can later locate those images and quits.

Your original images in folder or group are not added to the project.
You will not find any .atlas folders in your project and searching for the files will be unsuccessful.

Comment: Texture atlasing does this if your folders are groups (yellow) and have no actual directory structure. I've built my app with images organised into a directory structure, therefore one cannot just rename the folder name.atlas in order to create the atlas data. I can manually create the atlas data, but then I will have to rewrite my program in order to use it... I guess texture atlases may not be for me in this instance.